# Adding exceptions to the function

Tags: php

I have got a function which is use to take a string and convert it to the desired form i.e. Sentence case.

```
function sentence_case($string) {
$sentences = preg_split('/([.?!]+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$new_string = '';
foreach ($sentences as $key => $sentence) {
    $new_string .= ($key & 1) == 0?
        ucfirst(strtolower(trim($sentence))) :
        $sentence.' ';
}

$new_string = clean_spaces($new_string);
$new_string = m_r_e_s($new_string);
return trim($new_string);
}
```

Now I want to modify this function for " i ", as whenever we have I in out sentence than it remain capital how can I add exception to particular words like..." i ", " i' " etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\bi\b/', 'I', $new_string);
```

Comment: This will make `aaaaaa i aaaaa` into `aaaaaaIaaaaa`

Comment: in case of " i'" is it correct `preg_replace('/\bi\'/', 'I'', $new_string);

`

Comment: @Dani, it won't. `\b` is an anchor.

Comment: @Rahul Singh, the expression will replace `i`, ` i`, `i `, `i'`, `,i`, etc. You don't need to adapt it in any way for `i` followed by `'`. `\b` means "word boundary". Any `i` that is not part of a word will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a str_replace on the lower case string `$new_string = str_replace(' i ', ' I ', $new_string)`. String operations are less expensive than preg for simple replacements. However, you will need one exception for every pronoun.

Comment: On second thoughts, preg word boundaries are a much more elegant way to find words rather than assuming whitespace. +1 to Rahul's answer.

Comment: You will also need a different `str_replace()` call for each possible punctuation mark that might follow the `i`...